# How to make predictions using a saved RandomForest model from Orange GUI

Tags: python, python-3.6, pickle, random-forest, orange

I used Orange GUI and trained a RandomForest model that i later saved using the SaveModel widget.

Orange saves its models with pickle, therefore I went and wrote the following python script:

```
import Orange, pickle

model = pickle.load(open('model', 'rb'))
```

The problem is, I extensively searched the web yesterday. And couldn't find any example to make a prediction with my data (which is the same format as the data I used in the Orange GUI) or sufficient documentation on how to use the model.

Upon later research I found that I could supposedly evaluate a pre-trained model that was unpickled with the following code

```
results = Orange.evaluation.testing.TestOnTestData(data, test, [lambda testdata: model])
```

The thing is to load data I'm supposed to do:

```
data = Orange.data.Table('trainingData.csv');
test = Orange.data.Table('testData.csv');
```

And I haven't been able to find documentation regarding how to differentiate between the target and the features in these `*.csv` files.

Appart from that even if I'm able create this files. I would have to do some gimmick where `testData.csv` would need to be only one line long (the line I want to predict) with a target value of 1. And I would see what the model predicted by checking if the score was `100%` or `0%`

So I know my questions are multiple but I could really use some help on the follwing points:

1. How to define in a `*.csv` file what is the target among the features for the `Orange.data.Table()` function
2. How to use a pickled Orange RandomForest model to make a prediction instead of using a gimmicked evaluation to make a prediction. (So that i could predict more than one item at a time..)

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after questioning the same thing on Orange GitHub I managed to find an appropriate answer.

For the csv file format there is a documentation page on it where it explains how to define in the dataset what was a feature and what was the target:

[Documentation on Loading Data](https://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.io/loading-your-data/index.html)

As for the model it was ingenuously simple. The model is a python object used to make predictions so as soon as i have my data to be predicted formatted as said above on the documentation I can make a prediction by calling

```
pred_ind = model(data)
[model.domain.class_var.str_val(i) for i in pred_ind]  # convert to value names (strings)
```

and if I want to see the percentages all i need to do was

```
prob = model(data, model.Probs)
```

But better yet:

> As you can see in the example above, the model stores the domain it was trained on. This means you actually don't even need to bother with 1. When the model is given data to predict, it will first convert it to the domain it was trained on and use the same variables as the target and independent features (obviously they need to be present in the data).

If anyone wants the original answer on github here it is: [GitHub](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3225#issuecomment-418451951)